# jQuery: Math.floor function on hash load

Tags: jquery, html, math, jquery-isotope, hashchange

I have a hashchange function set up to change the class of divs and load them into an isotope grid, thus allowing me to navigate to the divs via a hash url. I also have a `Math.floor` function in there too as the height of `.grid-break` is determined by this, always in 230px intervals so it stays consistent with the grid. The `.click-block` click function show the `.grid-break` div at the correct height, this is great. But then navigating to this function via e.g. `www.website.com/#thisisahash` and the `.grid-break` div appears with no height and appears broken.
jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).hashchange(function () {
            var hash = location.hash;
            if (hash) {
                var element = $('.click-block[data-hook="' + hash.substring(1) + '"]');
                if (element) showDetail(element);
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).hashchange();

            var $container = $('#main-grid, #news-grid, .main-grid');

            $(function () {
                $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
                    $container.isotope({
                        itemSelector: '.grid-block, .grid-break, .hidden',
                        animationEngine: 'best-available',
                        filter: '*:not(.hidden), .grid-block',
                        masonry: {
                            columnWidth: 8,
                            gutterWidth: 25
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            $(".click-block").click(function () {
                document.location.hash = $(this).attr('data-hook');
            });
        });


        function showDetail(element) {
            var newHeight = $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).height();
            $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).removeClass('hidden').addClass('grid-break').delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
            newHeight = (Math.floor((newHeight + 10) / 230) + 1) * 230 - 10;
            $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).css('height', newHeight);
            element.children('.up-arrow').fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#post-' + element.attr('data-hook')).offset().top - 90
                }, "slow");
            }, 1500);
            $('#main-grid').isotope();
        }
});
```

Is there a way that the height of the `.grid-break` divs can be calculated before they're added to the isotope grid and thus appearing broken? Or any other solution to this small problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't compute the height of an unrendered element (that I'm aware of). You may be able to get by and use `visibility: hidden;` which would still take up real-estate but be invisible to the end-user.

Comment: @BradChristie thought so, it's odd though because the height is computed just fine on the click function (with the element still un rendered) just navigating to the hash URL that the height breaks. Or maybe there's a way of delaying the height calculation if a hash is present in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by firing the `math.Floor` function on window load like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $this = $('.grid-break');

        $this.css('height','auto');
        var newHeight = $this.height();
        newHeight = (Math.floor((newHeight+10)/230)+1)*230-10;
        $this.css('height',newHeight);
});
```